# How do I view a single file's history in GitK?

Tags: git, gitk

I have a git repository with a large number of files in it. At some point a bug was introduced into my program. I have a good idea which file is causing the issue, I just need to track down which commit introduced the error.

How can I view the revision history for single file using GitK?

Comment: Use `git blame` to find the commit that last changed a line. IIRC, `gitk` does support blame.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To get the file history

```
gitk <filename>
```

To see the blame history in a gui, which may help you track the commit use

```
git gui blame <filename>
```

Comment: Is there a way to view history for a file that has been renamed?

Comment: after calling gitk my terminal no longer shows my username and i can type but cannot execute any commands. How do i exit from that mode??

Comment: I was able to view history for a renamed file by using senooken's answer below

Answer (score 3):

You can just give the path of the file located at the dir. For example `src/foo.c`, you want to see the history of the file who changed it. In that case, you just need to give as `gitk src/foo.c &`

this will open a prompt and you can go through the history of the file.

Another way of viewing the history of file is `git blame` or if you want see which commit introduced the regression you can use `git bisect`

Comment: That then I mentioned in above statement it will run in background process, that's for the Linux environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on gitk by following steps.

1. Select [View]>[Edit view].
2. Fill file name to [Enter files and directories to include, one per line].
3. Select [OK] or [Apply].